# how to solve the problem with closing chan in golang

Tags: go, deadlock

Need to write a function that removes duplicates
but i am getting error what could be the problem

```
func remDup(in, out chan string) {
 for {
     val, ok := <-in
     if ok == false {
         break
     } else {
         if val != <-out{
             out <- val
         }
     }
 }
 close(out)
}


:fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Comment: `out` is probably empty, so `if val != <-out` just waits forever. If all your other goroutines are also waiting to receive or send, nothing can make any progress.

Comment: When describing a problem, a [mcve] is a good idea. Just showing one fragment of that cannot be used by itself leaves everyone guessing. I think the guesses you have are probably right, but ... they're *guesses*. In general it makes little sense to receive from a channel (`<-out`) *and* send on that same channel (`out <- val`) right next to each other as you are doing here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how `remDup` should work? From the question, function's implementation and the function's parameters, I can't relate. To be precise, be a little more elaborative about your question, and what should be the parameters and all.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you use **un-buffered channel** and **the channel is empty or the sender is not ready**, like this:

```
out := make(chan string)
```

This behavior is well explained in the [channel specs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types):

> If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready.

And also from [effective Go channel](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels)

> If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value

If you want to make receiver wait for any data from channel and you don't know whether the sender has send data to channel or not, use **buffered channel**.

```
out := make(chan string, 100)
```